# My modal window is not appearing as a pop-up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-window

My modal window is not appearing as a pop-up when clicked on "View Video". Instead its displaying just as any other div element in the same page. Can anyone please help.

```
<div class="content-intro">
       <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">View Video</a> 
    </div>  

    <div class="modal" id="myModal" style="display: none" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>                
             </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                My video 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: if `modal` looks like any other `div` on the page, it's likely that you have incorrect include path for bootstrap css file

Comment: Thanks a lot.! The include path for bootstrap.css file was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `data-target="#myModal"`

Just make your link like this

```
<a href="#" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">View Video</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the id and the class fade

```
  <div id="yourModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static">
```

And, how are you opening this modal?. It should be done with modal show

```
  $('#yourModal').modal('show');
```